# Creating a R function that builds data frames and exports content into folder

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm just wondering if I'm given a dataset like mtcars, how would I be able to export all rows and column names into a designated folder.  So ideally, my function would be one consisting of two arguments: the data frame and the folder?  Is it possible to do that or should I instead create a data frame from mtcars first, then export all rows and column names into a designated folder, with the folder name being another input?

In short, here's what I'm trying to do: Take the file, mtcars, create a data frame from it, get all the rows and columns names, and store them in a folder.

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you just trying to write the row and column names to a file, or the entire data set?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the colnames and rownames of a data table to two files use `write.table`:

```
write.table(colnames(mtcars), "file_cols.csv", row.names = F,col.names = F)
write.table(rownames(mtcars), "file_rows.csv", row.names = F,col.names = F)
```

If you want both in a single file you could concatenate the colnames and rownames:

```
write.table(c(colnames(mtcars),rownames(mtcars)), "file.csv", row.names = F, col.names = F)
```

The row.names and col.names options set to False will omit writing row numbers and a column name ("x").

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to do is this.  Take the file, mtcars, create a data frame from it, get all the rows and columns names, and store them in a folder.  I think what this does is store it in a file, right?

Comment: mtcars is already a data frame. If you have a file on disk, use the appropiate command (`read.csv` , `read.fwf`, `read.table`, `read.xlsx`, etc.). They all read the data as a data frame.  Commands `colnames` and `rownames` return the names.  To write this in a file use `write.table`